# Html Canvas - Translate, Rotate, Clip - Faster restores with using context.restore

Tags: html, canvas, restore

After asking a question regarding animation speed a few days ago, the stackoverflow gang once again solved my problem. However, this has led to another question. [The more you know, the more you realise you don't know.]

Basically the fewer state changes to my canvas, the faster things will go. If I am just changing the fillStyle, then using ctx.save and ctx.restore is overkill, as all states are restored. Overkill = Slow. Instead just keep the oldvalue of fillStyle somewhere and put just that back in once you have finished.

So how do you do this for ctx.translate(x, y), ctx.rotate(angle) and ctx.clip()?

How can I restore these guys to their states before my changes WITHOUT having to use ctx.restore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your can untransform by using negative values.**

```
ctx.translate(100,100);
// draw lots of stuff
ctx.translate(-100,-100);

ctx.scale(.75,.50);
// draw stuff
ctx.scale(-.75,-.50);

ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4);
// draw stuff
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/4);
```

If you do multiple transforms, you must undo them in reverse order

```
ctx.translate(100,100);
ctx.scale(.75,.50);    
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4);

// draw lots of stuff

ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/4);
ctx.scale(-.75,-.50);
ctx.translate(-100,-100);
```

But when translating (moving) a few items, it's faster to use an offset instead of a transform.

```
strokeRect(20+100,20+100,50,30);
fillRect(20+100,20+100,50,30);
```

Clipping is semi-permanent so you must save/restore the entire context state to undo clip:

```
context.save();
// define a clipping path
context.clip();
// draw stuff
context.restore();
```

Transforms are done using a transformation matrix.  Canvas gives you access to that matrix using the context.setTransform method.

```
scaleX=.75;
scaleY=.50;
skewX=0;
skewY=0;
translateX=100;
translateY=100;

context.setTransform(scaleX, skewX, skewY, scaleY, translateX, translateY);

// draw stuff

context.setTransform(-scaleX, -skewX, -skewY, -scaleY, -translateX, -translateY);
```

To also set the matrix for rotation, you must set a combination of the scale & skew values like this:

```
var radianAngle=Math.PI/4;
var cos=Math.cos(radianAngle);
var sin=Math.sin(radianAngle);

context.setTransform(cos,sin,-sin,-cos,0,0);

// draw stuff

context.setTransform(-cos,-sin,sin,cos,0,0);
```

To do rotation along with other transforms, just add the rotation values to the scale and skew values.

```
context.setTransform(scaleX+cos, skewX+sin, skewY-sin, scaleY-cos, translateX, translateY);

// draw stuff

context.setTransform(-scaleX-cos, -skewX-sin, -skewY+sin, -scaleY+cos, -translateX, -translate);
```

Comment: @markE: Hello, in the example above you wrote `sin=Math.cos...` - is that correct?

Comment: @d13 No, that's a typo on my part. Thanks for spotting it ... Corrected!

Comment: I think that this is wrong - you can not combine linear transformations (scale and skew) with trigonometric ones (rotation). The proper code is

Comment: I think that this is wrong - when combining transformations, you should multiply the individual matrices and not simply add values in the corresponding cells.

Answer (score 1):

Just to correct the assumption of the question :

False : • **The whole context state is saved/restored when using save()/restore() methods.**

Let's be modest : An idea that comes to mind in 30 seconds is most likely to be found (and improved) by the developers of major Browsers. So truth is :

True  : **• Saving the context does almost nothing, and restore applies only on what just occurred.**

If in doubt, you can look at the code, but it takes quite some time to be familiar with it (i did it with webKit's canvas => confirmed for this one ).
But it's much easier to look at the various jsperf made on the subject : they show that the gain when hand-saving/restoring one or two properties is moderate to small ==> only what changes is restored.
When hand-saving/restoring more things, then save and restore becomes *faster* because of Javascript's overhead.
(http://jsperf.com/save-restore-vs-translate-twice/4)

Another thing : talking about 'overkill' seems very exaggerated. Not only because, as seen before, context's save might be faster, but also because, *best* win is 2X, so we are talking about proudly taking 2ns instead of 4ns for the save. This has to be compared to the time taken for the draw, and might very well not be worth it.

Two last things :
• the bug risk induced by manually saving/restoring ('oops ! i forgot to restore that in that function !').
• the rounding errors that might occur  (scale(x,x) => then scale(1/x, 1/x) )

In fact you can save time with no risk is by :
1) batching commands : whenever possible (it all depends on your app, really), batch all commands that expects a given context state.
2) similarly, you can define conventions/rules that prevents you to save/restore the context. For instance : 'always set fillStyle just before filling'. This way you never have to worry about current fillSyle. What you can do here also greatly depends on your app (and wether it's using external APIs or not), but can save a great deal of time for numerous draws.

So my advice would be to use the manual save/restore only for obvious simple case (ex: you just change globalAlpha), and to use conventions/rules to reduce the context state changes to a minimum.